# Python chained comparison

Tags: python, django

I have this code:

```
if self.date: # check date is not NoneType
    if self.live and self.date <= now and self.date >= now:
         return True
return False
```

My IDE says: This looks like it should be simplified i.e. Python chained comparison.

What is a  chained comparison and how can it be simplified?

Comment: Not an answer, but are you certain that `self.age` will never be 0? Because then the first comparison will also be false; not just with `None`.

Comment: @Evert, yes thats true, let me update the OP.

Comment: https://www.google.co.in/search?q=chained+comparison+python

Comment: `self.date <= now and self.date >= now` doesn't that just means `self.date == now` anyway?

Comment: @njzk2 yes bad example but I understand the answers now.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

An example of a chained comparison is shown below.

```
age = 25

if 18 < age <= 25:
    print('Chained comparison!')
```

Note that beneath the covers this is [exactly the same](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#not-in) as shown below, it just looks nicer.

```
age = 25

if 18 < age and age <= 25:
    print('Chained comparison!')
```

Answer (score 4):

```
self.age <= now and self.age >= now
```

Can be simplified to:

```
now <= self.age <= now
```

But since it is True only when `self.age` is equal to `now` we can simplify the whole algorithm to:

```
if self.date and self.live and self.age==now:
   return True
return False
```

If you want to check if age is in some range then use chained comparison:

```
if lower<=self.age<=Upper:
     ...
```

Or:

```
if self.age in range(Lower, Upper+1):
     ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code can and should be reduced to:

```
return self.date and self.live and self.date == now
```

this is because:

1. `now <= self.date <= now` is mathematically equal to `self.date == now`
2. if you return a boolean depending on whether a condition is true, it's the same as just returning the result of evaluating the condition expression itself.

As to reducing `a <= b and b<= c`: it's the same as `a <= b <= c`; and this actually works with any other operator.

Answer (score 0):

To check if `x` is **superior** to `5` and **inferior** to `20`, you can use a **simplified chain comparison**, i.e.:

```
x = 10
if 5 < x < 20:
   # yes, x is superior to 5 and x is inferior to 20
   # it's the same as: if x > 5 and x < 20:
```

---

The above is a simple example but I guess it will help new users to get started with **simplified chain comparison** in `python`