# Strongness of Python == vs in operator

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I'm stumbling a bit why the following code

```
str1 = "text"
str2 = "some longer text"
if str1 in str2 == True:
    pass # do something
```

is not working. (I know that I can easily fix this problem by writing `if str1 in str2 == True:` - this is not the question!)

The question is, why is

```
str1 in str2 == True
```

returning `False`? I mean if the operator `in` is stronger than the `==` operator, I would have the following code

```
if (str1 in str2) == True:
```

which is actually working (as it will be evaluated to True) ... And if it is the other way round, that the `==` operator is stronger than the `in`operator, I would expect an `TypeError: argument of type 'bool' is not iterable` Exception. Actually the code

```
if a = "" in ("" == True):
```

is raising such an exception. So what is Python doing here? Which operator (`in` vs `==`) is evaluated first? And why is the result `False`:

```
a = ("" in "" == True)
```

and not `True` or an TypeError: argument of type 'bool' is not iterable`Exception? The only way I could imagine the`False` result is that Python is trying to execute both operators all together. But how is it working then?

**Things I noticed:**

- Python2 and Python3 are both showing the same result.
- The statement `"" in "" == ""` is actually returning `True`
- If you have the code `a = ("" in "" == True)`, `type(a)` will result in `<type 'bool'>`. So the result is actually a boolean - as expected - and not some kind of other object. Nevertheless `print(a)` results `False`.

Comment: There is absolutely no reason to ever write `== True` (\*except for very specific circumstances). Just do `if str1 in str2:`. What you're creating there is a *chained comparison*.

Comment: @deceze I know that there is no reason to ever write `== True`. I just wanted to know what is happening when you do it nevertheless. And neither https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25753474/python-comparison-operators-chaining-grouping-left-to-right nor https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24018315/python-chained-comparison is a duplicate. As explained in my question - when these operators would be chained, then the code `str1 in str2 == True`would either equal to `str1 in (str2 == True)` or `(str1 in str2) == True` however this is not the case.

Comment: Err, no, then you don't quite understand what a chain is yet. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/25753528/476 again. What you have is equivalent to `(str1 in str2) and (str2 == True)`!